# Reporting Services Extra Page Break

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010, reporting-services

I am having a problem with Reporting Services in VS2010 where it seems to be adding one to many page breaks to the generated report (pdf) and as a result I always end up with a blank page at the end of the report.

In my report there is a rectangle which contains a sub-report that could span multiple pages as well as a few other text boxes.  This rectangle has the PageBreak property set to End since I want a page break after each sub-report completes.

Any ideas on how I might get rid of this extra page while still maintaining page breaks between subreports?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: same problem here,however this occurs only at pdf documents!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, problem solved.
You shouldn't set the page break property to end at the rectangle but at the tablix group. It is not visible in properties. I think you should click Group Properties... There is a tab for Page Breaks!